# windows update Updateorchestrator restart after installation of updates Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update

Server 2016 windows updates are downloading and installing. But the server is never rebooting to apply the updates.

Configure automatic updating:   4 - Auto download and schedule the install
Install during automatic maintenance
Scheduled install day:  7 - Every Saturday
Scheduled install time: 00:00
Every week  Enabled
First week of the month
Second week of the month
Third week of the month
Fourth week of the month
Install updates for other Microsoft products    Disabled

Always automatically restart at the scheduled time is enabled for 15 mins

My understanding is Windows Update Orchestrator is in charge of scheduling the reboot. what does this task look like in windows scheduler? What log would I look at to see why it failed? The below says its scheduled, but days later still no reboot.

[image]

Comment: Questions about server administration are probably better suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

question moved to Server Fault.